# 'Cheatin’ uh?' Error When Attempting to Upload Images After 3.4 Update

Tags: multisite, images, uploads

Since updating my WP Multisite to 3.4, my subdomain admins get the 'Cheatin’ uh?' error whenever trying to insert images into posts / custom posts.  It seems to be a theme issue.

Comment: does your server run a lower version than PHP 5.3? If so, it doesn't support anonymous functions, which is why you are *probably* seeing that error. Read: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-settings-api-cheatin-uh-error

Answer (score 5):

So after trying pretty much all the solutions I found on google, I found the solution to my problem:

> Its possible that your theme uses some other theme options framework. If this is the case, you need to find the call to media uploader window and remove the `post_id` from it to fix the issue. The code will look something like this:
>
> `tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id='+jQuery('#post_ID').attr('name')+'&type=image&TB_iframe=1');`
>
> Replace it with this code:
>
> `tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?post_id=0&type=image&TB_iframe=1');`

More fixes here: http://www.agentwp.com/fix-cheatin-uh-error-in-wordpress

Comment: This is an under-documented issue on the Web.  Please accept this answer so the question is obviously solved.  (It's cool to accept your own answers, in case that was what was preventing you.)  Thanks for solving this.~

Answer (score -4):

I was trying to upload a logo on a new theme-Kept getting the cheatin uh? But after sometime i did solve this problem  by http://gauravseo.blog.com/2012/08/06/how-to-solve-cheatin-uh/

Comment: Changing core files (creating an WordPress fork) for such a trivial problem is the wrong solution in my opinion. Not recommended.